# How to establish the width of a column in a longtable

Tags: tables, longtable, width

I wrote a table by longtable. It works correctly but I would like to improve the layout of the width a column.
In the figure below you can see the result:[image]

As you can see, the last colums is very close to the page header, so I want to reduce the width of the column B (it has too much space that it does not need).

I tried to modify the width of columns B and C (column C is too far from column B) but the result does not change.

Can you help me?
I post also my code:

```
\landscape
\begin{longtable}{p{2.5cm}p{0.5cm}p{2cm}p{4cm}p{3.5cm}p{2.5cm}p{1.5cm}}

\caption{Table name.......................}
\label{tab:Summary} \\

\toprule
\textbf{AAAAAA} &\textbf{BBBBB} &\textbf{CCCCC} &\textbf{DDDDD DDDDDD} &    \textbf{EEEE EEEEEEE} & \textbf{IFFFF ffff} &\textbf{EEEEEEEEE}\\

\midrule
\endfirsthead
% intestazione normale
\multicolumn{2}{l}{\footnotesize\itshape\tablename~\thetable:
continued from previous page} \\
\toprule
\textbf{AAAAAA} &\textbf{BBBBB} &\textbf{CCCCC} &\textbf{DDDDD DDDDDD} &    \textbf{EEEE EEEEEEE} & \textbf{IFFFF ffff} &\textbf{EEEEEEEEE}\\
\midrule
\endhead

\midrule
\multicolumn{2}{r}{\footnotesize\itshape\tablename~\thetable:
Continued on next page} \\
\endfoot
% piede finale
\bottomrule
\multicolumn{2}{r}{\footnotesize\itshape\tablename~\thetable:
It ends from the previous page.} \\
\endlastfoot
% corpo della tabella
AAAAAA al. & AAAAAA & BBBBBBB & description description description description & description description description description description & bbbbbbb & aaaaaa and bbbbb\\

\hline
AAAAAA al. & AAAAAA & BBBBBBB & description description description description & description description description description description & bbbbbbb & aaaaaa and bbbbb\\

\hline
AAAAAA al. & AAAAAA & BBBBBBB & description description description description & description description description description description & bbbbbbb & aaaaaa and bbbbb\\

\hline
AAAAAA al. & AAAAAA & BBBBBBB & description description description description & description description description description description & bbbbbbb & aaaaaa and bbbbb\\

\hline
AAAAAA al. & AAAAAA & BBBBBBB & description description description description & description description description description description & bbbbbbb & aaaaaa and bbbbb\\

\hline
AAAAAA al. & AAAAAA & BBBBBBB & description description description description & description description description description description & bbbbbbb & aaaaaa and bbbbb\\

\hline
AAAAAA al. & AAAAAA & BBBBBBB & description description description description & description description description description description & bbbbbbb & aaaaaa and bbbbb\\

\hline
AAAAAA al. & AAAAAA & BBBBBBB & description description description description & description description description description description & bbbbbbb & aaaaaa and bbbbb\\

\hline



\end{longtable}
\endlandscape
```

Can you help me?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Use a larger number in the `\multicolumn` declaration of the footer.

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand your suggestion. I modified my code in this way: \multicolumn{4}{r}{\footnotesize\itshape\tablename~\thetable: (i replaced 2 with 4 in the three declaration of the footer) but in this way the columns are overlapped. Can you help me?

Comment: Make the BBB column larger again, 0.5cm is not enough.

Comment: why don't you use `l` and let the table make columns that match the data rather than specifying the column width with  `p{0.5cm}` and then saying teh column is too wide?

Comment: `\landscape` .. `\endlandscape` is wrong and will have weird effects in the rest of the document. use `\begin{landscape}`.. `\end{landscape}`

Answer (score 5):

for single-line entries it's more natural to use `l` and let the table find the natural width of the content, also you need to allow the note in the foot to span more columns. Also `landscape` is an environment.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{longtable,pdflscape,booktabs}

\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
\begin{longtable}{lllp{2cm}p{4cm}lp{3.5cm}}

\caption{Table name.......................}
\label{tab:Summary} \\

\toprule
\textbf{AAAAAA} &\textbf{BBBBB} &\textbf{CCCCC} &\textbf{DDDDD DDDDDD} &    \textbf{EEEE EEEEEEE} & \textbf{IFFFF ffff} &\textbf{EEEEEEEEE}\\

\midrule
\endfirsthead
% intestazione normale
\multicolumn{7}{l}{\footnotesize\itshape\tablename~\thetable:
continued from previous page} \\
\toprule
\textbf{AAAAAA} &\textbf{BBBBB} &\textbf{CCCCC} &\textbf{DDDDD DDDDDD} &    \textbf{EEEE EEEEEEE} & \textbf{IFFFF ffff} &\textbf{EEEEEEEEE}\\
\midrule
\endhead

\midrule
\multicolumn{7}{r}{\footnotesize\itshape\tablename~\thetable:
Continued on next page} \\
\endfoot
% piede finale
\bottomrule
\multicolumn{7}{r}{\footnotesize\itshape\tablename~\thetable:
It ends from the previous page.} \\
\endlastfoot
% corpo della tabella
AAAAAA al. & AAAAAA & BBBBBBB & description description description description & description description description description description & bbbbbbb & aaaaaa and bbbbb\\

\hline
AAAAAA al. & AAAAAA & BBBBBBB & description description description description & description description description description description & bbbbbbb & aaaaaa and bbbbb\\

\hline
AAAAAA al. & AAAAAA & BBBBBBB & description description description description & description description description description description & bbbbbbb & aaaaaa and bbbbb\\

\hline
AAAAAA al. & AAAAAA & BBBBBBB & description description description description & description description description description description & bbbbbbb & aaaaaa and bbbbb\\

\hline
AAAAAA al. & AAAAAA & BBBBBBB & description description description description & description description description description description & bbbbbbb & aaaaaa and bbbbb\\

\hline
AAAAAA al. & AAAAAA & BBBBBBB & description description description description & description description description description description & bbbbbbb & aaaaaa and bbbbb\\

\hline
AAAAAA al. & AAAAAA & BBBBBBB & description description description description & description description description description description & bbbbbbb & aaaaaa and bbbbb\\

\hline
AAAAAA al. & AAAAAA & BBBBBBB & description description description description & description description description description description & bbbbbbb & aaaaaa and bbbbb\\

\hline



\end{longtable}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```